# Read values from Excel Text Box using C# - Nuget Package

Tags: c#, .net, excel, nuget-package, epplus

I have an existing excel file, from which I am trying to read data and store it in the DB. But there are few Text Boxes and Check Boxes, where I need to get data from these as well. Is anyone aware of how I can get these values from Excel using C#(Any Nuget package available). For getting the cell values I am using EPPlus.

Note: The excel format is fixed and cannot make any changes to that.

Any kind of help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: EPPlus does not support form controls, See this [FAQ](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/FAQ) for general list of what is and is not supported.

Comment: @J.Salas is there any other package which I can use to get values from controls?

Answer (score 0):

Free Spire.XLS NuGet package is capable of reading form controls in Excel: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.XLS

The basic example below explains how to read value from a textbox and a checkbox in an Excel worksheet.

```
using Spire.Xls;
using System;

namespace ReadFormControls
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            workbook.LoadFromFile("test.xlsx");

            Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            //Get the text of the first text box
            string text = worksheet.TypedTextBoxes[0].Text;
            //Get the state of the first check box
            CheckState state = worksheet.TypedCheckBoxes[0].CheckState;
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.WriteLine(state.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Excel:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: That helped me a lot. But still no option to read value from a ActiveX controls. Just now I found that the textboxes I was talking about are ActiveX textbox and not the normal one. I went through the documentation of Spire.XLS and it seems like there is no option to read from ActiveX controls